# wp_loaded hook block script enquequing

Tags: php, plugin-development, hooks

I have a cutsom maintenenace screen generated by a plugin for non admin users. I need to setup a countdown timer on it if an option on the related settings page is enabled. I've implemented the Settings API correctly I'm able to save and retrive the checkbox selected or not option value and other stuff. I need some help to enqueue the front-end style, I need to pass to the javascript file some data outputted by the back-end settings page, I want to avoid inline scripting. I've tried using the normal wp way to load scripts `wp_enqueue_script`, but it will not work, I'm not sure why?
I'm using the following code to show the maintenance page. Is possible that the `wp_loaded` hook will block the styles and scripts enquequing?

```
public function maintenance_mode()
  {
    global $pagenow;
    if( $pagenow !== 'wp-login.php' && !current_user_can('manage_options') && !is_admin() ){
      header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable', true, 503 );
      header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
      if( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/maintenance.php' ) ) {
              require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/maintenance.php';
          }
      die();
    }
  }
// the add action is in a separate method
add_action( 'wp_loaded', array($this, 'maintenance_mode') );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't enqueue because `wp_loaded` is too early.

To enqueue scripts and styles, you need to do it on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` type hooks, but because your exiting on `wp_loaded`, none of those hooks have fired yet.

Additionally, you need to have the necessary function calls in the template for it to enqueue them into, such as `wp_head` or `wp_footer`, otherwise there is no opportunity to generate the script and link tags

So your options are:

- use a later hook than `wp_loaded` that happens after the scripts have been enqueued
- include the scripts manually inline

Comment: what hook i can use ? In the template I'm loading the scripts for now manually, but because I need to fix the enquequing.